# How can I return false when scrolling down?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I found a lot of examples of console logging scroll direction. But even though I tried modifying almost all of them to return a value instead, I couldn't make them work.

My goal is to check the scrolling direction when entering a specific viewport, and return false if the scrolling direction is down. Then I want to use the false value in a exitviewport function to only then send **ONE** ReactGA event of scrolling. My attempts have either resulted in 'cannot read property of undefined' error or to **a lot of** events which I do not want. I think my main problem is combining a return with the fact that there is a reassignment that needs to be reached by the code.

My code so far is:

```
//this code I found and it seems to work

onEnterViewPort () {
  window.onscroll = function (e) {
   console.log(this.oldScroll > this.scrollY);
   this.oldScroll = this.scrollY;
 };
}


//used console logs to check.

onExitViewPort () {
  console.log('I have left the viewport.')

 // ReactGA.event({
 //   category: 'Scroll',
 //   action: 'Scrolled down',
 // });
}
```

which I use in

```
<ScrollTrigger onEnter={this.onEnterViewPort} onExit={this.onExitViewPort} triggerOnLoad={false}>
        <div >
          <thingshere>
        </div>
</ScrollTrigger>
```

Please help a noob out!

Comment: You should check out IntersectionObserver, which is less demanding that listening to every single scroll event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score 0):

Example with jQuery.
This will start to display the scrolling direction after u entered the Viewpoint the first time, so you would need to create another funtion for the onExitViewpoint event...

```js
$.fn.onEnterViewport = function (callback) {
  var $window = $(window);
  
  return this.each(function () {
   var that = this;
   var oldHeight = 0;
   $(document).on('scroll', function () {
    var docHeight = $window.height();
    var myTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var myOffset = $(that).offset();

    var top = myOffset.top - myTop;
    
    if(top < docHeight){
     callback(oldHeight, top);
    }
    oldHeight = top;
   });
  });
 };

$('.viewpoint-in').onEnterViewport(function(oldHeight, newHeight) {
  if (oldHeight > newHeight) {
   console.log('Scroll Down')
  } else {
   console.log('Scroll Top')
  }
 });
```

```css
*{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.viewpoint-out {
  background: red;
  height: 1000px;
}

.viewpoint-in {
  background: white;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="viewpoint-out"></div>
  <div class="viewpoint-in"></div>
 <div class="viewpoint-out"></div>   
</section>
```